# Automatic alignment reversal with Right-to-Left HTML

Tags: html, css, right-to-left

we have a pretty complex HTML application which also supports RTL.
However when switching the HTML to RTL by using the `<html dir='rtl'>` attribute not everything is reversed.
Especially elements that were aligned previously by CSS do NOT reverse.

Simple example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<table>
<tr><td>Some text long text</td><td>Even More long text</td></tr>
<tr><td style='text-align:right;'>aligned to right</td><td>aligned to left</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

When setting

```
<html dir='rtl>
```

on this example I would expect the text-align to switch direction, too. But it doesn't. For this reason we currently load a 2nd template CSS file after the default one that overwrites the necessary alignments. I feel that this is not optimal.

Is there is easier way to reverse/flip alignment stuff for RTL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want something like this

```
html[dir="rtl"]
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/3UsyS/

Comment: Thank you. The solution is not as light as I have hoped for but at least a step into the right direction.